# Set MATLAB's default character set to UTF-16 accidentally, now it seems broken

Tags: matlab, utf-8, utf-16

I did this in MATLAB

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-16');
```

I was trying to see if that would allow me to display an overscore `‾` in some text, which always displayed as a `?`.

So now everything errors. I do feel a little dumb, but there should have a warning or a confirmation dialog. I can reinstall, if that is my only option, but do I have any another options?

Comment: I was able to replicate this in R2015b on OS X. `feature` is an undocumented function so I suppose that you use it at your own risk. However, it's never a good thing for a function screw up this way. You might consider [creating a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs) to report this bug. Also, you should be able to produce an [overscore/overline](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203e/index.htm) with `char(8254)`.

Comment: thanks for the tip on overlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Restart.***

It *seems* to be a temporary setting, what threw errors then, is fine now.

Also never run this:

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-16');
```

*This will **not** work if you do run the above **:***

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-8');
```